# Syntax Highlighting for Template Toolkit (.tt files) in VIM

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugin, template-toolkit, vim-syntax-highlighting

My goal is to get syntax highlighting for files using extension `*.tt` and so far it's been a frustrating "no" every time.

I found the `vim-perl` plugin. Installed using legacy method 'make install' and nothing happened. Tried using Pathogen as well.

The files I'm trying to enable syntax highlighting for have extension `*.tt` and I notice vim-perl has `tt2.vim` files.

I'm not an expert at VIM, but I'm pretty sure I've installed it correctly. Assuming this much, should changing any of vim-perl's files named `tt2.*` to `tt.*` work (which I've tried, and it doesn't)?

What gives?

Comment: Can you post the output of `:set ft` when you are in a `.tt` file. The output should be the name of the syntax file (with a .vim extension).

Comment: it actually returns `filetype= ` (no file type assigned).

Comment: Can you post a link to the plugin so I can look at it? It seems like the filetype detection isn't being set properly.

Comment: I pulled the plugin from https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl and ran a make install with it. I ran `set filetype=tt2` and it enabled highlighting actually. Though it doesn't apply it to the HTML portions of the file. I'm not familiar with the plugin so I'm not sure if that's normal - though this is a step forward.  How can I associate `.tt` files to use the the tt2 filetype everytime?

Comment: Try typing `set filetype=tt2html` and see if that gets better syntax highlighting. I put how to associate all `.tt` files as `tt2` in an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file at `~/.vim/ftdetect/tt.vim` that contains the following.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tt setf tt2
```

This should associate all `*.tt` files with `tt2` filetype.

Comment: Now everyone knows what a noob I am. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @sunday Everybody starts somewhere and vim can be very complicated.